# Stop a process from running on startup without removing it

Tags: ubuntu, startup, postgresql

Just for the heck of it I was running `pgrep postgres` and got a ton of results:

```
postgres  1882     1  0 10:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf
postgres  1883     1  0 10:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/postgresql/9.4/bin/postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/9.4/main/postgresql.conf
postgres  1943  1883  0 10:07 ?        00:00:00 postgres: checkpointer process                                                                                              
postgres  1944  1883  0 10:07 ?        00:00:00 postgres: writer process                                                                                                    
postgres  1945  1883  0 10:07 ?        00:00:00 postgres: wal writer process                                                                                                
postgres  1946  1883  0 10:07 ?        00:00:00 postgres: autovacuum launcher process                                                                                       
postgres  1947  1883  0 10:07 ?        00:00:00 postgres: stats collector process                                                                                           
postgres  1948  1882  0 10:07 ?        00:00:00 postgres: checkpointer process                                                                                              
postgres  1949  1882  0 10:07 ?        00:00:00 postgres: writer process                                                                                                    
postgres  1950  1882  0 10:07 ?        00:00:00 postgres: wal writer process                                                                                                
postgres  1951  1882  0 10:07 ?        00:00:00 postgres: autovacuum launcher process                                                                                       
postgres  1952  1882  0 10:07 ?        00:00:00 postgres: stats collector process
```

First off I think it's a little weird that postgres9.3 and 9.4 seem to be running at the same time, but that's a bit of a separate issue.

I don't need postgres to run on startup, though I can start it with `sudo service postgres start` as needed. I'd like to start 9.4, though.

I've looked into updating startup processes, but it doesn't seem like there is a hard-and-fast way to do this and answers typically surround creating your own startup scripts.

It seems like my best bet would be to remove or unlink `/etc/init.d/postgres` somehow, but I'm not quite sure of the best way to go about doing this. I have `/etc/rc{2,3,4,5}.d/SO3postgresql` as well and they all seem to link to the `init.d` script. What would be the best way to prevent a script from starting on boot -- particularly postgres?

Comment: Can you find an `Application Autostart` setting, on ubuntu Settings? I'm on xubuntu and looks like this: http://imgur.com/UdHrtRw

Answer (score 3):

Use `update-rc.d` to turn on and off services during startup.

`update-rc.d postgres remove`

`update-rc.d` takes care of all the links in your /etc/rcX.d directories.

Note: this doesn't remove the startup script from /etc/init.d, just all the links in the /etc/rcX.d directories!

See [update-rc.d man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/update-rc.d.8.html) for more information.

EDIT I didn't realize you were using ubuntu, so I looked up the equivalent.